# Meaning of 運動神経が良い

Tags: definitions

I just got told:

> 背高いし運動神経良さそう

Apparently 運動神経 means [motor nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_nerve):
[image]

What does `運動神経が良い` mean in this context? The conversation was about swimming, not something where reflexes are that important I believe.

Comment: Swimming as in competitive swimming? In which case reflexes would certainly be important I think...

Comment: @kuchitsu Low-level competition yes.

Answer (score 5):

In this context it does not have much to do with reflexes or nerves.

It just means "good at sports".

References:

- [運動神経が良い 【形】 sportistic](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%81%8B%E5%8B%95%E7%A5%9E%E7%B5%8C%E3%81%8C%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84)
- [運動神経: スポーツや技能などを巧みにこなす能力](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/21629/meaning/m0u/)

Answer (score 1):

> A motor nerve is a nerve that carries command information out of the central nervous system (CNS) and toward effectors (muscles or glands) that will execute the commands.

Even if we take this definition literally, I think the expression ”運動神経が良い” is not too off. If we take motor nerve is good as transmitting information efficiently from CNS to muscles efficiently, I think it applies to real movement in sports.

Answer (score 1):

> 運動神経 = motor nerves, reflexes
>
> 運動神経がいい = motor nerves, reflexes are good

Speaking of physical abilities, if your motor abilities or reflexes are good, chances are that you're the athletic type. It does take a good amount of reflex  and reaction whenever playing a sport, especially for competition's sake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's also a common way to express "gifted at sport(nerve)". Since it's mainly talking about physical capacity as talent.